# Favorite Questions and Answers from third quarter 2018

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from July 1st 2018 through September 30 2018 (**They don't have to be *your* questions and answers, but it also doesn't matter if you want to self promote your own stuff.**).

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/07/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/07/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/07/01)

**I will also be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter. Also the most controversial question of the quarter. Also a sum of all the bounties that were awarded.**

Also if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

[image: I got a tattoo of the invisible man, the artist assured me it looks great. The nice thing was I felt nothing.]

Answer (score -2):

[Do any of the Hogwarts founders have living descendants?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191215/do-any-of-the-hogwarts-founders-have-living-descendants)